# Dynamically change google map width after init?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to know how to dynamically change the width of my google map canvas after init.  so my map comes up fine, but its in a pane, and when the user adjusts the pane "center" becomes "off center".    I have a method to get the new width from the pane, but need to tell the map its new width.  how do I do that?

Comment: Reset the map center after the resize

Comment: won't work, I don't know what latlong constitutes center to set it too.  because the width of the map is 100% of the resolution screen at init.   I only know the fixed px after init (which is when the pane is adjusted).

Comment: How did you originally center the map?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue as it is otherwise impossible to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in jsfiddle or something because the map is in a pane.  This screenshot should help explain my issue:
http://temp.extremehosting.ca/trash/gmap.jpg
I set center to be a lat/long in the visible map (eg. Southern Utah), but the map think its much larger as shown by the red box.  so it drags the map center to the real center of the box.  so its always off.  I simply need a way to tell my map (after init and shown) the new width is now X, not the red box's width it thinks and wants.

Answer (score 0):

I see, you can use .gm-style.  Set the width of the div.gm-style to its new width, then call resize.  thats all I needed.

```
jQuery('.gm-style').css({'width': iNewMapWidth + 'px'});
google.maps.event.trigger(mapObject, "resize");
```